# Does adding joins change the result set

Tags: c#, sql

I have a query that joins two tables, I think it is an inner join in SQL because I am using Entity Framework's syntax.
So I have something like this:

```
from s in this.Table1
join a in this.Table2 on s.somefield equals a.somefield
where ( // same conditions.... )
//
```

and then I have another one with one extra join:

```
from s in this.Table1
join a in this.Table2 on s.somefield equals a.somefield
join b in this.Table3 on a.anotherfield equals b.anotherfield
where ( // same conditions .... )
//
```

Comment: Yes.  That is why you use joins.

Comment: Why didn't you just look at the result sets? You would have immediately answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "join" (short for "inner join") produces rows from Table1 and only those from Table2 where the "ON" clause is true.

for example Tables:

```
Person (ID, Name)
1, 'Bob'
2, 'Ted'
3, 'Jill'

Book(ID, BookName, PersonId)
1, 'SQL', 2
2, 'EntityFramework', 4

Select *
From Person
INNER JOIN Book on Person.ID = Book.PersonId
```

This will produce the results from both tables only where "Person.ID = Book.PersonId":

```
ID, Name, ID, BookName, PersonId
2, 'Ted', 1, 'SQL', 2
```

So in your case, each inner join you add in will further restrict the final result set depending on each JOIN\ON clause! Hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing it changes the result. In your first query you get the matching records between Table1 and Table 2, which meet some criteria -in you where clause-, while in the second query you get the matching records between tables, Table1, Table2 and table3, which meet some other criteria -in you where clause-. As you see the result sets are differents and as already Gordon pointed out in his comment, *that is why you use joins*.